# Drupal 7 taxonomy term nodes sort by WEIGHT

Tags: drupal, drupal-taxonomy

I've created content type called 'price' and defined field called 'weight'. Also I've created field 'Taxonomy term reference'. When clicking on Taxonomy term it shows all nodes related to this term. But How I can sort them by WEIGHT field?

At this moment I've created pages for all terms in views(I was lucky, I've got only 8 terms). But if terms would be more than 8. How can I automate this process? I would like create only one views for all terms.

Answer (score 1):

Define Views for field reference -> node listing -> add relation for taxonomy term -> add sorting for this relation.

Comment: any link to tutorial, please?

Comment: I cann't found certain example, but you can just find any example with relation...